# How to get the current test name for Playwright in TypeScript?

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

Here is what I have implemented for NUnit when using Playwright.  I would like to do the same thing for TypeScript with Playwright.

```
public string GetTestClassMethod()
{
    return $"{TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.ClassName}.{TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName}";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can extract some meta info about the file and actual test using typescript.

This info can be fetched from `TestInfo` class.

Here is an example:

```
test('random test', async ({ page }, testInfo) => {
    await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

    console.log(testInfo.title);
    console.log(testInfo.titlePath);
});
```

output:

```
random test
tests\\dummy.test.ts
```

Here is official documentation for this functionality:
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testinfo

Another way to fetch such info is trough reporter class, with its hooks:
More info: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-reporter